# Use first 4 terms of the series to approximate

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need to use the first 4 non zero terms binomial Taylor series:

$(1+x)^r = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {(r n)x^n}$
centered at $0$

I need to use this series to approximate $(1.2)^{1/4}$.

What exactly is the question asking me to do? This topic is new to me so I am not sure how to start this problem.

Comment: $x=0.2,r=0.25$. Need I say more?

Comment: I can see how you got there, but how does that relate to the terms of the series?

Comment: Notice that your summation uses $r,x$ as variables. I gave you their values...